# ‘have been’ VS ‘were’

Tags: past-tense, mood

1. He said with a smile as if he were talking about an old friend.
2. He said with a smile as if he had been talking about an old friend.

What the difference between two sentences?

Comment: Neither one of those is a complete sentence . . .

Answer (score 1):

They are both ways of expressing something that is counterfactual: who or what he is speaking about is not an old friend.  It could be a stranger, an enemy, or even a comfortable pair of old shoes, say. He is speaking of the subject as if speaking about an old friend.

*as if he **were...*** uses the subjunctive form of the verb BE, and *as if he **had been...*** uses a back-shifted tense (past perfect of BE).

P.S.  Consider the following. Assume as a contextual fact that "She" has never been to this bar before:

> She walked up to the bar and greeted the man tending bar as if she had been coming to this bar for years.
>
> She walked up to the bar and greeted the man tending bar as if she were a regular customer.

The phrase "as if she had been coming to this bar for years" refers to a counterfactual condition which, if it were true, would predate the action of walking up to the bar and greeting the bartender.

The phrase "as if she were a regular" refers to a counterfactual condition which, if it were true, would be contemporaneous with the action of walking up to the bar and greeting the bartender.

Comment: Can you help me analysis their meanings?

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot, not if you did not understand the opening paragraph.

Comment: Can you change two sentences to direct references?

Comment: I do not know what you mean.

Comment: If the sentence 1 is counterfactual, it should use 'had been', because it happened in the past.

Comment: Counterfactual ≠ happened in the past.

Comment: If it happened in the past, I want to use counterfactual, so I should use 'had been'. If it happens  now, I want to use counterfactual, so I should use 'were'. Am I right?

Comment: It never happened.  The subject was never his friend.  *He said* refers to a past statement.

Comment: In the past statement, I should use 'had been' in the counterfactual situation. Why did he use 'were'?

Comment: They are both statements about the past. He said...   The "time" of the thing that was not true is "never".

Comment: If I were you, I would see a beautiful film. If I had been you, I would have seen a beautiful film. So in the past we should use ‘had been’.

Comment: Sorry, "as if" is not "if". You're mistaken.

Comment: what is the meaning of ‘BE’?

Comment: BE is the bare infinitive of I am, you are, he|she|it is, we are, you (plural) are, they are.

Comment: I look happy as if I had money. I looked happy as if I had had money. When can I say ‘ I looked happy as if I had money?

Comment: You can say that about a time when you had no money. Are you looking a photo?

Comment: I look happy as if I had money now.      I looked happy as if I had had money yesterday.    When can I say ‘ I looked happy as if I had money?

Comment: You can say "I looked happy" when referring to  how you looked in the past, and "as if I had money" would mean "like a man with money", though you were not such a man.

Comment: I know this. What I don’t know is why I can write ‘ I had had money’ or ‘I had money’.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that the "as if" construction is necessarily counterfactual. If you didn't know what the man was talking about, you might guess it was an old friend and use this phrase.

Comment: @Tim Foster:  I think "like old friends" would be used to describe something that could be true whereas "as if old friends" describes a mere semblance.

Comment: Here's an example from Harry Potter, in reference to Muggles: "Their eyes slid from the big book shop on one side to the record shop on the other as if they couldn't see the Leaky Cauldron at all." Here Harry does not know whether Muggles can see the Leaky Cauldron. They can't, but the "as if" construction is still fine.